# Error Returning UIImage from PFFile function getDataInBackground

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, parse-server

I am struggling to return a UIImage from a Parse Function.
I'm fairly new to return functions but I have got Parse and well now I am trying to make a global function which I can reference in MVVM schema instead of continuously repeating the code throughout my app.

The function works perfectly without the return statement added (-> UIImage), I just can't get a UIImage then.

```
func fetchImage(imageFile : PFFile) ->  UIImage
{
    var image : UIImage!

    imageFile.getDataInBackground { (data, error) in
        if error == nil
        {
            image = UIImage(data: data!)
        }
        else
        {
            print(error!)
            image = default-img
        }
    }

    return image
}
```

I'm sure it's a simple error I'm making, I just can't seem to find anything about adding a return statement to a parse function.

Comment: This won't work. You are missing the fact that `getDataInBackground()` is asynchronous. There are plenty of question about that. Look for "Swift + Closure + Asynchrone"

Comment: @Larme can you link to a question which would help me out? I'm not really familiar with Stackoverflow, quite the novice if I'm being honest with you /: